# Excel Userform Search filter does not bring and displays the data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Userform where i look for some personal data in a sheet called "Hoja4". In one of the pages, i can add some more data that its send to another worksheet where a sheet is called "Hoja1". 
So, when i go to another tab, where i search by ID or by Surname, to filter that data, sometimes it brings me the data of that person, but mostly it does not. Its the same code for both searches and autocomplete some textboxes that just differ their names, but in different pages inside a userform. Its weird that im looking for the same data with two different codes but it only works properly on one and barely on the otherone.

What it brings when i press search? It brings the names of the columns where that data is stored. I leave here the code.

```
Private Sub btnBuscar2_Click()
    'declarar las variables
    Dim FindRow
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cRow As String

    'error block
    On Error GoTo errHandler:

    'Filtrar solo por Legajo
    If Me.BLeg2 <> "" Then

        'Encontrar la fila con la data
        cRow = Me.BLeg2.Value
        Set FindRow = Hoja4.Range("A:A").Find(What:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)


        'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Leg2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Fech2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Ape2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Nomb2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Pues2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)

        'Filtrar solo por Apellido
    ElseIf Me.BApe2 <> "" Then

        'Encontrar la fila con la data
        cRow = Me.BApe2.Value
        Set FindRow = Hoja4.Range("B:B").Find(What:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)


        'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Leg2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, -1)
        Fech2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Ape2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Nomb2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Pues2.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
    Else
        MsgBox "Por favor, ingresar un Legajo o un Apellido"
    End If

    'error block
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Error! Verificar los datos ingresados, porque no son correctos!" & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: What i found is that, if i just click on the first ID textbox, and then look for an surname, it works like charm. I think the problem its on the if and else statement. I tried changing `If Me.BLeg2 <> ""` to  `If IsNull(Me.BLeg2.Value) then`  but even if i add and ID or a Surname that exists or both, it just triggers the msgbox from the last part of the code

Comment: I thought its bcz textbox = "" it applies only if i enter the box and there is nothing on it... which makes sense, so if i don´t click on it, it should be null? Yet, i can´t find the solution so far.

Comment: Update, i have to desactivate the text that appear inside the textbox that was a caption to let the user know what goes inside. It appeared when the userform loaded up but dissapear when the user cliked insided the button. I think the problem was within that manner. If anyone can give me a hand over that, if that may be the problem, the code its pretty short...